# I need only one slanted sans serif math character

Tags: fonts

For some reason I need one slanted sans serif character. Otherwise in my documents I use Fourier, Helvet and Luximono fonts. How to determine it?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
    \usepackage{fouriernc}
    \usepackage[scaled=0.83]{helvet}
    \usepackage[scaled=0.82]{luximono}
        \usepackage{marvosym,pifont}

    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    \usepackage{mathtools,xspace} 

\newcommand{\T}{\ensuremath{\mathsf{T}}\xspace}

    \begin{document}
I like \T to be slanted and sans serif character. I use it in text as well in equations: 
    \[\T = a + b \quad\mathrm{and}\quad \int_\T = \cdots    \]
How to achieve this with considering used fonts?
    \end{document}

![enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: It's “sans serif”. :-) `\newcommand{\slT}{\text{\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries\slshape T}}`

Comment: of course, but it seems that I need one sheriff who will find me this `sans serif` T :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\text`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[scaled=0.83]{helvet}
\usepackage[scaled=0.82]{luximono}
\usepackage{marvosym,pifont}


\usepackage{mathtools} 

\newcommand{\T}{\text{\sffamily\bfseries\slshape T\/}}

\begin{document}

I like $\T$ to be a slanted and sans serif character. I use it in text as well in equations: 
\[
\T = a + b \quad\text{and}\quad \int_\T = \cdots
\]
How to achieve this with considering used fonts?

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As usual I discourage using `\ensuremath` and `\xspace` for this. It's a mathematical symbol, so it should *always* be used in math.

Comment: thank you for comment about `ensuremath` and `xspace`. Regarding T: it is slightly smaller then roman T. Is this feature of used sans serif fonts that uppercase characters are less tall as roman at same heights as small cap characters?

Comment: @Zarko Do `\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{helvet}`: *you* were telling LaTeX it should be smaller. `;-)`

Comment: yes I do (a long time ago, and I do not remember for what reasons. Now I try to remove  `helvet` fonts and result is in this MWE better, but in real document cause me an error. About it I need deeper look in my document preamble ...

Comment: I found source of error: it is `ntheorem` package. If I use `ensuremath`, than errors disappear. So temporary I return to it's use.

Comment: @Zarko Make another question with the details and a really minimal example.